# Using older VMC on Ruby 1.9.3 - Error: "Can't convert hash into string"

Tags: ruby, cloud-foundry, vmc

I recently installed Ruby 1.9.3 on my Win7 PC.  I then installed the most recent version of VMC, and it appeared to be running fine.  I was advised, however, to uninstall that version because it doesn't work correctly in my environment, and instead install 0.3.21.

I have done so, but I now get the following errors with basically every VMC command that I enter.  I have tried re-installing Ruby, Sinatra, and VMC, but still get the same errors.  Any ideas?

```
C:\$eclipse\TestProjectRuby>vmc -v
can't convert Hash into String
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vmc-0.3.21/lib/cli/commands/base.rb:60:in `expand_path'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vmc-0.3.21/lib/cli/commands/base.rb:60:in `block in load_manifest_structure'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vmc-0.3.21/lib/cli/commands/base.rb:59:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vmc-0.3.21/lib/cli/commands/base.rb:59:in `load_manifest_structure'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vmc-0.3.21/lib/cli/commands/base.rb:81:in `load_manifest'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vmc-0.3.21/lib/cli/commands/base.rb:28:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vmc-0.3.21/lib/cli/runner.rb:465:in `new'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vmc-0.3.21/lib/cli/runner.rb:465:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vmc-0.3.21/lib/cli/runner.rb:14:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/vmc-0.3.21/bin/vmc:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/bin/vmc:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby193/bin/vmc:23:in 'main'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why were you advised to uninstall the most recent version? There may have been gem dependency issues but they have been resolved.